# PhantomJS --debug to file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Debugging an issue with PhantomJS.. I added the command line param --debug=true and now I'm swamped by an ocean of debug messages but only on the console. Is there a param to direct the debug output to file?

I tried output redirection but that didn't work oddly enough..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer... the 'debug' messages were actually being written to sterr not stdout. So output redirection worked fine using

> phantomjs.exe XXXXX > logfile.txt 2>&1